# Django - CheckboxSelectMultiple without "------" choice

Tags: django, django-widget, django-forms

How can I remove "------" from rendered choices?
I use in my model form:

```
widgets = {
    'event_form': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
}
```

In model I have IntegerField with choices:

```
EVENT_FORM_CHOICES = (
    (1, _(u'aaaa')),
    (2, _(u'bbbb')),
    (3, _(cccc')),
    (4, _(u'dddd')),
    (5, _(eeee'))
)
```

rendered choices contain --------- as first possible choice. How I can get rid of it?

EDIT:
The only working way i figured out is (in **init** method):

```
tmp_choices = self.fields['event_form'].choices
del tmp_choices[0]
self.fields['event_form'].choices = tmp_choices
```

but it's not very elegant way :)

Comment: What does your `event_form` field look like in your model?

Comment: @Alasdair `event_form = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(max_length=2, choices=EVENT_FORM_CHOICES)`

Comment: See my answer below. As an aside, I don't think `max_length=2` makes sense for an `IntegerField`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django is including the blank choice because the field doesn't have a default value.

If you set a default value in your model, then Django will not include the blank choice.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    event_form = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=EVENT_FORM_CHOICES, default=1)
```

If you don't want to set a default value in your model, then you can explicitly declare the field and choices in the model form, or change the choices in the model form's `__init__` method.

Answer (score 3):

Update

a similar example maybe useful:

```
country = ModelChoiceField(reference_class = Country, choices= country_choices, 
required=True, empty_label=None,  widget=forms.Select)
```

If you want a solution client side instead:

```
<script>     
$("#selectBox option[value='-----']").remove(); 
</script>
```

Comment: initial: None - is this correctly inserted? I get error "name 'initial' is not defined".

Comment: No, it gives me an error: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'initial'

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem but fixed it this way. First, download and install https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-multiselectfield. If you don't know how to install, look here: [django-multiselectfield can't install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27332850/django-multiselectfield-cant-install). Then, in models.py:

```
from multiselectfield import MultiSelectField

CHOICES_FOR_ITEM_WITH_CHOICES = (
            ("choice 1", "choice 1"),
            ("choice 2", "choice 2"),
            ("choice 3", "choice 3"),
        )
class MyModel(models.Model):
        item_with_choices = MultiSelectField(max_length=MAX_LENGTH, null=True, blank=True)
```

In admin.py:

```
from .forms import MyModelForm
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = MyModelForm

    list_display = ('item_with_choices',)
    list_filter = ('item_with_choices',)
    search_fields = ('item_with_choices',)

admin.site.register(MyModel, MyModelAdmin)
```

In forms.py (you can name this whatever you like):

```
from .models import MyModel

class MyModelForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = (
            'item_with_choices',
            )

    def clean(self):
        # do something that validates your data
        return self.cleaned_data
```

This builds off the answer here: [Django Model MultipleChoice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27440861/django-model-multiplechoice/27442810#27442810)