# django-multiselectfield can't install

Tags: python, django

I am trying to install https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-multiselectfield this Django module. I am total noob, so I don't know what to do after `git clone https://github.com/goinnn/django-multiselectfield`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install it after cloning it.

Go to that directory and install it using:

```
python setup.py install
```

Or you can download the tar.gz file and go to the download directory and install it using `pip install <name-of-file-here>`.

Once the installation is complete, you can use it in your app by specifying `'multiselectfield'` in INSTALLED_APPS of your settings file and using the field in your models (this is documented on their site), assuming you're using the same python environment for Django where you've installed this package.

Answer (score 1):

Install it using pip3 or pip:

```
pip3 install django-multiselectfield
```

or

```
pip install django-multiselectfield
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `multiselectfield`entry in the `settings.py` file.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # ...
    'multiselectfield',
)
```

After that you can use new field type in `models.py`

```
from multiselectfield import MultiSelectField

class MyModel(models.Model):
    my_field = MultiSelectField(choices=MY_CHOICES)
```